# How to rewrite API content in IIS ARR response

Tags: xml, api, iis, url-rewriting, arr

There is a secondary API call by my web application after the main page loads. This API call contains XML data with URLs that need to be rewritten as well but don't get rewritten.

The URLs in the XML response from the API call all need to be rewritten to the same domain as the external domain the call came from.

I have tried using Precondition `<add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^application/xml" />` and using Precondition `<add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />`

Both don't seem to work.

The configuration used is below:

```
<rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1">
    <match filterByTags="None" pattern="^http(s)?://k2.denallix.com/(.*)" />
    <conditions>
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" value="https://k2.reverseproxy.com/{R:2}" />
</rule>
<preConditions>
    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^application/xml" />
    </preCondition>
</preConditions>
```

There is no error from Failed Request Tracing but the GENERAL_RESPONSE_ENTITY_BUFFER shows the response in the XML has not rewritten the URL.

Multiple instances of `<Data>https://k2.denallix.com/Runtime/Runtime/View/Authorization+view/?SN=408849_21</Data>`

should actually rewrite to `<Data>https://k2.reverseproxy.com/Runtime/Runtime/View/Authorization+view/?SN=408849_21</Data>`

Thanks.

Comment: According to your description, I suggest you could try to use fail request tracing to capture the details logs for the outbound rule.  It will contain the details steps about the url reiwrte works. More details about how to use it to troubleshoot the url rewrite, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules).